# php echo de tag html como texto

Tags: php, query, oracle, echo

Tenho uma consulta em php/oracle que ao mostrar o resultado no browser, oculta uma tag **"< /b>"** enquanto que no oracle sql developer apresenta tudo ok.

O esperado: '___< /b>'

O que apresenta no browser: '___'

O resultado no oracle sql developer:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( "AUXILIARES_ACESSOS_DB", "SOLICITACAO_", ""), "_DB",""), "AUXILIARES_",""), "PRJ_","") DEMANDA, bg.BG_BUG_ID DEFEITO, bg.BG_STATUS STATUS, bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_09 SIR_ENCAMINHADA_PARA, bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_03 SISTEMA, bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_01 NATUREZA_ERRO, bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_05 ETAPA_TESTE, remove_html_tags(final_substr(bg.BG_DEV_COMMENTS,"___</b>")) COMENTARIO FROM AUXILIARES_ACESSOS_DB.BUG bg WHERE bg.BG_STATUS NOT IN ("Pendent (Retest)", "Closed", "Rejected", "Cancelled", "On_Retest") AND bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_09 IN ("GA - CSC", "GA-OI", "GA - OI") UNION ALL
```

A consulta php/oracle:

```
$sql = "SELECT TESTE FROM VW_ZEND_BUG";
$result = odbc_exec($conOraSql , $sql);
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row["TESTE"], "<br />";
}
```

O resultado no browser pela consulta php/oracle:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( 'AUXILIARES_ACESSOS_DB', 'SOLICITACAO_', ''), '_DB',''), 'AUXILIARES_',''), 'PRJ_','') DEMANDA, bg.BG_BUG_ID DEFEITO, bg.BG_STATUS STATUS, bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_09 SIR_ENCAMINHADA_PARA, bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_03 SISTEMA, bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_01 NATUREZA_ERRO, bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_05 ETAPA_TESTE, remove_html_tags(final_substr(bg.BG_DEV_COMMENTS,'___')) COMENTARIO FROM AUXILIARES_ACESSOS_DB.BUG bg WHERE bg.BG_STATUS NOT IN ('Pendent (Retest)', 'Closed', 'Rejected', 'Cancelled', 'On_Retest') AND bg.BG_USER_TEMPLATE_09 IN ('GA - CSC', 'GA-OI', 'GA - OI') UNION ALL
```

Comment: Você que exibir todas as tags dessa string?

Comment: esse é o resultado e sim, todas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para imprimir código php ou html como texto puro pode usar a função [highlight_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php).

```
<?php
$str = '<p><b>texto</b></p>';
highlight_string($str);
```

A saída de `highlight_string()` é quase a mesma de [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), exceto pelo `<code>` e `<span>`.

```
<?php
$str = htmlspecialchars('<p><b>texto</b></p>');
echo $str;
```